# display message for currently logged user

Tags: powershell

in our company we use itsm software, it has a built-in module for remotely running all sorts of scripts. Before executing the script updating the given software, I would like to inform the user about the need to save the work and close the software. while the update part is rather standard, I have a problem with informing the user.
There is an agent installed on each computer in our ITSM and this agent executes all running scripts and this is where the fun part begins.

At first I had an idea:

```
#some code

$user = $environment:USERNAME

msg $user pls save your work and close the app

sleep 30

#check if app is still open

#e.t.c
```

But here comes the first problem, the agent starts its own session so the variable

$env:username = [$env:computername]$ which is computername with $

i checked few methods how to find logged user, like

```
query user /server:$SERVER
```

on local session, it works fine, but remotely gives an error message:

`query: The term "query" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or op program. Check Check the spelling of the name, or if a path is included, verify that the path is correct and try again`

finally i found solution to return logged user:

```
$user = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem | % Username
write-host "User: " $user
```

or

```
$explorerprocesses = @(Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='explorer.exe'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
If ($explorerprocesses.Count -eq 0)
{
      "Explorer process not found/no one logged in interactively"
}
else
{
      ForEach ($i in $explorerprocesses)
      {
          $Username = $i.GetOwner().User
          Write host "$username"
   
      }
}
```

but when im trying to use msg

```
msg.exe $username test
```

I'm getting this error:
`msg.exe: The term "msg.exe" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operating program. Check k spelling of the name or if a path is included, check that the path is correct and try again.`

i've tried to add full path msg.exe but that won't do the work either.

I found some other methods to display messages via ps( like $wshell.Popup)  but at this point i start to wonder if its possible to display something for another user/session w/o knowing credentials?

Any ideas or hints how to solve this?

Comment: msg.exe sends only to currently logged in users on that system, but that error suggests it can't find the executable where it's being run.  Maybe compare `cmd /c where msg` to `pwd` and see if they are the same drive?   I would think providing the full path would resolve that though, but if they are different you might have to cd first before calling msg